# How to create a custom store in dstore for xml document

Tags: xml, dstore, xmlstore

I am trying to use dstore custom Stores, I am wondering how to create a custom store for xml document.  Could some one help me out?

Comment: What is it that you have tried and failed with? Any code you maybe can provide?

Comment: I have not tried any thing, but I am wondering what can I do using this tutorial http://dstorejs.io/tutorials/custom_stores.html to make work using xml file. and the xml file is local not remote on my machine. Could someone help me out?